# Publish reports from VS2015 Error shows wrong URL

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I added a report project to my existing solution in VS2015, built some reports and now I am trying to deploy the project to a report server.  I have gotten the URL from the config manager ( http://MyServer/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS ) and put that in the report project properties as the target server URL.

When I click Deploy I get an error saying "The specified report server http://localhost/reportserver could ot be found.

I have no idea where it is getting this localhost reportserver URL from, that is not what is saved in the properties. The Report project is inside a solution with an MVC project. Do I need to change something at the Solution level?

Comment: Did you tried to Clean and then Rebuild project? Also, manual removing of bin/ folder may help.

Comment: Yep tried both of those, no help.

Comment: Are you deploying to report server located on your local machine? If so, then try to use http://localhost/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS or http://localhost:8080/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had to run VS as an administrator, I assume because of the permission on the remote server.